# Different source and testSource JDKs for a maven project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project imported in IDEA. There is a submodule which uses different versions of java for the regular and test sources - it uses java 1.4 for the regular sources, and java 7 for the test sources, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.4</source>
        <target>1.4</target>
        <testSource>1.7</testSource>
        <testTarget>1.7</testTarget>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The project compiles fine when using maven, but fails to compile in IDEA. When I open the Project Structure -> module settings, I see that the module is imported with Language level of 1.4. Because of this, the compilation of the test classes fails, as they use features not available in 1.4.

As a workaround, I manually change the java version in pom.xml. Is there a way to do it without having to modify the maven configuration?

**Edit**: As suggested in the comments, I changed the setting manually in Project structure inside IDEA, but I get the following error when compiling the project:

```
Information:3/20/2015 5:29 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 5 sec
Error:java: javacTask: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7
```

Comment: As far as i know there is only one Java version support per module. Why you do not want to use 1.7 while developing? Lets say intellij uses 1.7 and Maven still compiles it using 1.4. I think it will work. Other alternative is make your test project to another module.

Comment: @bhdrkn I tried changing the setting in IDEA, but I got the strange looking error I added to the question.

Comment: Defect: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately different language levels for source and tests are not supported by Idea yet. Appropriate bug was opened in JetBrains issue tracker back in 2012: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478

As a workaround I do the following each time I import (i.e. after I make any changs to pom.xml) my maven project into Idea:

1. Go to `Project Structure` (*Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S*), open your module and set Language Level to *1.7*
2. Open `Idea settings` (*Ctrl+Alt+S*), search for `Java compiler` ang change the target bytecode version of your project to *1.7*

The downside is that Idea wont know that your non-test sources should be compiled for 1.4 and will offer you to make changes available in Java 1.5+ only

Another solution would be to extract the tests into a separate Maven module (it will be imported to Idea as a separate Idea module) and set a different language level for it, i.e. specify testSource lvel as 1.7 only for module containing your tests